# Add SSL on mysubdomain.parseapp.com

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, cloud, ssl-certificate, hosting

I've created a subdomain for my parse app and I need to protect the connection while logging and during my session.

Assume that I don't have any public domain name and I will still use just the url of (mysubdomain.parseapp.com) then is all I need to get buy a certificate and get the two files for:

SSL Public Certificate
SSL Private Key

and just upload it to parse through the settings page ? or will I need to do something else ?

Just need a confirmation that my understanding is correct.

Kind Regards,
Robear

Answer (score 0):

The private key would come from the server. A Certificate Authority is only going to give you a domain cert. For example "mysubdomain_parseapp.com_crt" and yes you'll need to upload the domain cert, private key (which is generated during the CSR request), plus the CA's intermediate cert (the CA should advise which one and where to download it).

In order for a CA to issue out a cert. You need to own the root domain or have permission by the owner. In your case you would need to prove that your the owner or have permision to purchase an SSL cert with "parseapp.com"